# create list lists from a .mtx file

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, file

I have to write a function that takes a matrix of numbers from an `Mydata.mtx` file and create a list of lists for each row.
*Mydata.mtx file is just a simple file with number matrix as shown below*

for clarification here is the matrix from the file:

```
1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15
```

the function should take return a lists of lists for each row:

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'], ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15']]
```

I'm unable to get this (above), but instead keep getting this (below):

```
[['1', ' ', ' ', ' ', '2', ' ', ' ', ' ', '3', ' ', ' ', ' ', '4', ' ', ' ', ' ', '5', '\n'], ['6', ' ', ' ', ' ', '7', ' ', ' ', ' ', '8', ' ', ' ', ' ', '9', ' ', ' ', ' ', '1', '0', '\n'], ['1', '1', ' ', ' ', '1', '2', ' ', ' ', '1', '3', ' ', ' ', '1', '4', ' ', ' ', '1', '5', '\n']]
```

here is the code:

```
#print statements are just to see what my output would be
def readMatrix(filename):
    listOfLists = []
    file = open(filename, "r")
    for i in file:
        iList = list(i)
        listOfLists.append(iList)
    print(listOfLists)



callFile = input("Enter the file name: ")
toReadFile = readMatrix(callFile)
```

extra info:

a second function should transpose this matrix

after which a third function creates a new file `T.Mydata.mtx`

(but I can try to figure out these later. my main problem is the first function

Comment: Where is your code? It looks like you just need to strip out the spaces.

Comment: @PaulRooney yeah sorry I forgot to add.. it should be there now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple fix is to use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) without a `sep` argument, to remove all the whitespace between the numbers.

```
def readMatrix(filename):
    listOfLists = []
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i in f:
            listOfLists.append(i.split())
    return listOfLists


callFile = input("Enter the file name: ")
toReadFile = readMatrix(callFile)
print(toReadFile)
```

It could also be expressed more succinctly using a list comprehension.

```
def readMatrix(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        return [line.split() for line in f]
```

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help. I greatly appreciate it

Comment: Oh I didn't know about that. just thought str.split() actually equals str.split(' ')

Comment: I added a link to the docs which explains it. Also if you want to transpose the matrix, can you use numpy or are you looking to implement it yourself?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I'm trying to solve this code without using imports. I have used ```[list(i) for i in zip(*M)]``` in the second function to transpose the matrix. so far it works, but would need to change it so it would accept empty matrices too

Comment: What does an empty matrix look like? Is it `[]` or `[[]]` or something else?

Comment: @PaulRooney the latter ```[ [ ] ]```

Comment: and zip does not work for the empty matrix? How so?

Comment: @PaulRooney in the original file, if there is an empty row in the matrix , it would produce an empty file

Answer (score 1):

### Problem:

Looks you have some extra spaces

### Solution:

```
import re

# should be imported from the file
m = """1   2   3   4   5
6   7   8   9   10
11  12  13  14  15"""

m = re.sub(' +', ' ', m) # replaces extra spaces with one single space

numbers = list(map(lambda row: row.split(' '), m.split('\n')))
# numbers == [['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], ['6', '7', '8', '9', '10'], ['11', '12', '13', '14', '15']]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but is there a way without importing?